# Why is setxkbmap in .xsession not working?

Tags: login, 15.04, keyboard-layout

Currently I have to run `setxkbmap gb` every time I restart my system.  This started happening since I upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04 with systemd.  It used to work putting this command in the `.xsession` file, which still starts my window manager and changes the cursor and so on.  Here are its contents:

```
xsetroot -cursor_name left_ptr
feh --bg-fill ~/wallpapers/luke-twyman-wallpaper-1920x1200.jpg
setxkbmap -layout gb
xmonad
```

Also, the actual system console is set to the correct gb locale and the keyboard layout is fine.  This problem is only with X.

Also it may be relevant that I use the text login, which I enabled with `systemctl set-default multi-user.target`.  I don't really understand why that command has this effect but I guess that would be another question.

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm running xmonad on trusty with lightdm, and for some reason, `setxkbmap` won't work in the `.xsession` file for me either. I'm still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try this (it helped me):

1. Run `ibus-setup`.
2. Click *Advanced* tab.
3. Click *Use system keyboard layout*.